# Getting stdin while connected to a server Python

Tags: python, stdin, irc

I'm connecting to an IRC server but while it's sitting waiting for data I'd like the program to be able to grab input from the terminal and then relay it to the server, so essentially say JOIN #foobar  and the program send JOIN #foobar. The current code looks like:

```
def receive(self):
    while True:
        raw = self.socket.recv(4096).decode()
        raw_split = raw.splitlines()
        if not raw:
            break
        for line in raw_split:
            #if line.find('MODE {0} :'.format(self.config['nick'])) > -1:
                # placeholder for perform
            data = line.split()
            if data[0] == 'PING':
                self.send('PONG {0}'.format(data[1]))
            color_print("-> {0}".format(data), 'yellow')
            #self.plugin.run(data)
```

Any ideas how to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at the [select module](http://docs.python.org/library/select.html). You can use it to wait on multiple file-like objects including a socket and stdin/stdout/stderr.

There's some example code at [this site](http://ilab.cs.byu.edu/python/select/echoserver.html).